# Announcement: Article of the Week Chat Room established

Tags: discussion

So, I found an interesting article by Scott Adams, and I was interested in getting people's responses to it.  As a for instance, he asks the question, Is Religious Belief a Talent or a Handicap, and what's the difference.

In general, I suspect that we, as members of this site, regularly find articles like this worth discussing, so I'm proposing a chat room where we can do just that.  If you look for the "Article of the Week," I think it'll be worth your while :)

Comment: My thought process was that this would (a)generate a few "answers" that could be followed separately.  Mostly I thought it was an interesting article, and I was curious about some of the reactions it would generate.  In chat, I'm afraid the chain would get too tangled to follow.

Comment: (I *knew* this didn't belong on main! :))

Comment: yeah, I think the problem here is that we just don't have a place suited for this yet...perhaps its own dedicated chat room?

Comment: link it in the room!

Comment: So, who's responsible for picking the article each week? Because [I might have one or two suggestions](http://timothy.green.name/links/category/religion/christianity/).

Comment: Good question :)  I say if the conversation is lagging for a day, feel free to post a new article

Answer (score 2):

This is about Christianity more than it is about this site, but it's not formulated in a way that would work as a main site question. It's discussiony rather than answerable. Chat does sound like a better place.

Maybe you could use meta to organize regular "feedback" chat events to talk through these kind of current events. If you get a little interest here we can certainly back you up with the official chat room event logistics (although you might have the rep to do it on your own anyway).

**Edit:** The [Article of the Week](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2975/article-of-the-week) chat room has been established for this purpose.

Comment: ooh article of the week chat anyone?

Comment: That is a brilliant idea. "Article of the Week".  I'll set up the chat room, then make a general announcement for it?

Comment: @AffableGeek sounds great. If you want to declare a new article day then I can make a chat event that will get notification on the main site.